# ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file in AWS EC2 Linux

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpexcel

I am working on cron jobs in laravel 5.2, when i try to call a controller function from schedule to create excel sheet getting Error. but runs fine in postman.

`ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary: No such file or directory' in /var/www/html/Expenses/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:398`

Problem with temp file permission for zipArchive?

I am getting above error while save phpexcel sheet to directory(777).

```
$excel_path = 'SubmittedSheets/'.$userId.'-'.uniqid().'.xlsx';
$objWriter->save($excel_path);
```

Comment: Does the folder that you have configured as a temp folder for PHP actually exist? If so, does your script have access to it? (Remembering that a cron job may be running as a different user that a web access)

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/ziparchiveclose-failure-to-create-temporary-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @hassan - I saw this solution but not clear. please explain if you know.

Comment: @MarkBaker - I did not configure any temp folder. the path i given is PHPExcel.

Comment: Configuration of a temp folder for PHP is nothing to do with PHPExcel; it's a part of your PHP/OS configuration. You can find what it's set to by using PHP's [sys_get_temp_dir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) function

Comment: @MarkBaker - Problem with php zip extension or temp file permission?

Comment: Check the value of that temp folder, and check permissions

Comment: @MarkBaker - I do not know where phpexcel stores temp files, and aws linux tmp has 1777 permission.

Comment: ZipArchive and PHPExcel should use sys_get_temp_dir()

Comment: But permissions alone don't say much without knowing what accounts have privilege to access the folder, and what account is being used to run your php script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143696/discussion-between-151291-and-mark-baker).

Comment: @MarkBaker - I added absolute path to save, then runs fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need Absolute path to save excel file in AWS Ec2 Linux for PHPExcel.

```
$excel_path = '/var/www/html/MyProject/public/SubmittedSheets/'.$userId.'-'.uniqid().'.xlsx';
$objWriter->save($excel_path);
```

Comment: I have same error but solution is not working :( , even i used -- $objWriter->save('/var/www/yebesis/public_html/files/caglar.orhan/test.xlsx');

Comment: @caglaror - It happens due to low disk space too, check your AWS  available space, hit `df -h` and `du -sh`. please let me know error message as well.

Comment: No, it has a lot of space :(

Comment: I am not on AWS Ec2 but I had same problem on Centos7 configured on Azure. sys_temp_dir was empty. I had to go in edit php.in to set tmp directory path to fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it on my Mac OS system by simply uncommenting the line

```
;sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```

in `php.ini`, i.e. changing it to

```
sys_temp_dir = "/tmp"
```

> Directory where the temporary files should be placed.
>   Defaults to the system default (see sys_get_temp_dir)

Not sure which directory it tried to use as default though, possibly `/var/tmp`, which my Homebrew PHP installation doesn't seem to have permission to write to.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot of things and spend a lot of time. Solution for Ubuntu + Vesta + Nginx + Apache was in file:

```
:/home/admin/conf/web/your-domain.com.apache2.ssl.conf
```

set up tmp folder like in my example:

```
<Directory /home/admin/web/your-domain.com/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
    SSLRequireSSL
    Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    php_admin_value open_basedir 
    /home/admin/web/your-domain.com/public_html:/tmp
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /tmp
    php_admin_value session.save_path /tmp
</Directory>
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFJkO.png)

don't forget to restart the apache service